# Selecting date only column in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have this piece of code:

```
{ 
    if ($4 ~search) 
    {
        match ($4, /([0-9]{2}\/([a-zA-z]{3})\/([0-9]{4}))/, dates)

        print dates[1] "\t" dates[2] "\t" dates[3]
    }
}
```

and when it is run it produces this:

```
[19/Oct/2012:12:34:32
[19/Oct/2012:12:34:32
[19/Oct/2012:12:34:33
```

So in theory it is working and producing some of what I want but how do I get it to just produce `19/Oct/2012` any suggestions?

My questions is that I would like the output to just produce the date 19/Oct/2012?

Comment: why sometimes `dates` sometimes `date`? typo?? can you paste somemore codes? or input??

Comment: Your regexp and your output don't match at all?

Comment: Edit your question, and paste a few lines of input, please. The solution *might* be as simple as `BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}`. Without valid input, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Edited code to make the question more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regexp:

```
{
    match ($4,/[0-9]{2}\/[a-zA-z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}/,date)
    print date[0] 
}
```

Will output:

```
19/Oct/2012
19/Oct/2012    
19/Oct/2012
```

Notes:

- Your current `regexp` looks for dates with numerical month *e.g*
  `19/10/2012` not `19/Oct/2012`.
- Your capture groups are missed matched *(Unbalanced parenthesis)*.
- In your given example the year is `20012` not `2012`!?
- You go from `dates` to `date`.
- `date[0]` stores the whole match whilst `date[n]` refers to the nth capture group.

There may be a better approach to your overall problem but it's impossible to say with the very little *(and very erroneous)* information given.

**Edit:**

The only issues that seems to be left is the misplaced capture group.

```
{
    match ($4, /([0-9]{2})\/([a-zA-z]{3})\/([0-9]{4})/, dates)    
    print dates[1] "\t" dates[2] "\t" dates[3]
}
```

Will output:

```
19    Oct   2012
19    Oct   2012
19    Oct   2012
```

But in your question you state you want the output in the format `19/Oct/2012` *(which is what my first suggestion does)*!?

Comment: Hey thank you but this doesnt work but thanks anyway for the notes they are quite helpful.

Comment: @user2160949 the *new* code you added gives no more clarification and the only problem you seem to have fixed is the correct use of `dates` instead of `date` all the regexp issues I have highlighted you have not fixed. You need to update the question with sample lines of your input and describe what you are trying to do along with expected output as I have already highlighted your syntactical errors.

Comment: Hey changed it again the 20012 was a typeo, also print[0] is the same as what im printing anyway so produces same outcome

Comment: Instructions to get help: **1.** read my answer **2.** fix the regexp issues my answer points out *(see bullet points 1 and 2)* **3.** Update your question with some sample input, describe the problem you are trying to solve and the issues you are having and add the expected output of the script. Once you have done these 3 steps it will be clear to everybody what the problem is and how to solve it and you will get lots of great answers!

Comment: ok I can only apologise for the confusion, I have made the changes that were highlighted by sudo_O

Comment: @user2160949 see edit, please upvote this post if it was helpful and accept it if your problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the errors in your code sample and output, if all you want to do is strip out the leading `[`, then you could just `substr` the match starting at the 2nd character:

```
print substr(date[0], 2)
```

However, I suggest revising your regular expression to output the correct match to begin with.

Comment: If you want to do it properly, do what sudo_O suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15479679/551467